# How to create payload in AsyncApi?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, asyncapi

My code works ok, but I need help with my documentation in `nestjs-asyncapi` and `swagger`. In my code, I have an object in the array, but in the documentation I have only an object.

[image]

This is my nest js decorator:

```
@AsyncApiSub({
    channel: 'myChannel',
    description: 'Read all features - result',
    message: {
        name: 'getFeaturesResponse',
        payload: {
            type: () => Feature,
        },
        headers: AsyncApiHeaders.subHeaders(),
    },
})
```

And now I created this part of my async API in Async API studio and everything looks ok, exactly like I want. But I don't know how should I update the decorator in order to have array

```
"Feature": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "idFeature": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "unique id of Feature",
          "example": "example"
        },
      },
    },
    "required": [
      "idFeature",
      "name",
      "description"
    ]
  },
```

This is what I want.

[image]

Should I provide more information? Should I rewrite somehow the whole decorator or only some parts? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that right now `nestjs-asyncapi` doesn't know how to do it. So one way is to update the script that will do that.

Or I choose one other option. I added into my dto class another dto as an array. Both are in the same file.

```
export class Feature {
    @ApiProperty({
        type: 'string',
        description: 'unique id of Feature',
        example: 'a5f3252b-1007-449d-a75d-e99ecf88bc06',
    })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsString()
    idFeature: string;

    constructor(
        idFeature: string,
    ) {
        this.idFeature = idFeature;
    }
}

export class FeatureArray {
    @ApiPropertyOptional({
        type: Feature,
        isArray: true,
        description: 'settings of Feature',
    })
    @ValidateNested({ each: true })
    @Type(() => Feature)
    @IsArray()
    featureArray: Feature[];

    constructor(
        feature: Feature[],
    ) {
        this.featureArray = feature;
    }
}
```

This is decorator in my code:

```
    @AsyncApiSub({
        channel: 'myChannel',
        description: '',
        message: {
            name: 'Name',
            payload: {
                type: () => FeatureArray,
            },
            headers: AsyncApiHeaders.subHeaders(),
        },
    })
```

And here is result as image:

[image]